# change slider tab on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, slider

I wanna make this content slider works by mouse over.
this is default jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/6WXkM/2/

would you please someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the event property (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover) in initialisation :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}, event: "mouseover"}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```